# Unobserved Task exceptions in .NET 4.5 still crash app

Tags: c#, .net

In [Steven Toub's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx):

> To make it easier for developers to write asynchronous code based on
> Tasks, .NET 4.5 changes the default exception behavior for unobserved
> exceptions.  While unobserved exceptions will still cause the
> UnobservedTaskException event to be raised (not doing so would be a
> breaking change), the process will not crash by default.  Rather, the
> exception will end up getting eaten after the event is raised,
> regardless of whether an event handler observes the exception.

But the result of my experiment does not match the above statement. Below is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DownloadAsync("http://an.invalid.url.com");
}

async static void DownloadAsync(string url)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        string text = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} chars", text.Length);
    }
}
```

Since I pass an invalid url to `DownloadAsync()` method, the call to `HttpClient`'s `GetStringAsync()` method will throw an expcetion, and it crashes the application.

So my question is: Does unobserved exceptions in .NET 4.5 still crash app by default?

Comment: It's not unobserved, accessing the text.Length is an implicit wait.

Comment: @Jesse Isn't it the assignment of the result to `text` that causes the result to be observed, rather than the later use of `text.Length`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are totally right, in my mind it was a task but of course it's not.

Comment: Observing exceptions can be done explicitly (read Task.Exception property) or implicitly (use await or one of the blocking methods). More infos: https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/Unobserved-Exceptions

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You do have a `Task` with an exception (the one returned by `GetStringAsync`). However, the `await` is observing the `Task` exception, which then propagates out of the `DownloadAsync` method (which is `async void`).

Exceptions propagating out of `async void` methods behave differently; they are raised on the `SynchronizationContext` that was active when the `async void` method started (in this case, a thread pool `SynchronizationContext`). This is *not* considered an unobserved exception.

If you change `DownloadAsync` to return `Task`, then you will have an actual unobserved `Task` exception, which will be ignored (correctly):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  DownloadAsync("http://an.invalid.url.com");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

async static Task DownloadAsync(string url)
{
  using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
  {
    string text = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} chars", text.Length);
  }
}
```

Comment: @StephenCleary : Very informative! This is not something you come across every day so I'm curious as to where you came across such in-depth knowledge of this particular mechanism. Care to share the book or article?

Comment: @Anthony: .NET reflector, lots of questions (mostly on MSDN forums), and years of experimentation. I am, however, currently *writing* a book. :)

Comment: @StephenCleary did you ever actually complete your book?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: Yes, I did. It's available from [O'Reilly](http://tinyurl.com/ConcurrencyCookbook) or [Amazon](http://tinyurl.com/ConcurrencyCookbookAmazon) (both affiliate links).

Comment: That `async void` methods are behaving differently from `async Task` ones is an eye-opener. Thank you!